# Polyan's Step? (1980) Alpha Step Size Name?

Tags: algorithms, convex-optimization

In class we're reviewing different $\alpha$ step sizes, and one of the step sizes was called the "Polyan's Step (1980)." It was defined as...
$\alpha_{k} = \frac{f(x_{k})-f^*}{||g_{k}^{2}||}$, where $f^*$ is a solution to the problem.
However, when I tried googling this name, nothing came up. Is this the correct name for the step size or is it typically called something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That step size is due to Roman Polyak.  It appears that either the lecturer misremembered the name or the note taker made an error.

Comment: Thank you, the k looked like an n because it was written small :/